# DirectX 11: Runtime crash when running simple DirectX application

Tags: c++, class, winapi, inheritance, directx

I've attempted to inherit some public globals from a base class and successfully got the window up and running and initialized directx similarly in a simple way- in it's own class, inheriting globals, such as `HWND hWnd`.

However when the program is run, `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()` fails. On further inspection, debugger gives:

`DXGI ERROR: IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain: No target window specified in DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC, and no window associated with owning factory. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #6: ]`

The  `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC` structure is as follows:

```
SwapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = 1024;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = 768;
SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
SwapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
SwapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;
SwapChainDesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
```

Where `hWnd` is stored in:

```
class Infinity{
public:
    Infinity();
    ~Infinity();
    HWND hWnd;
};
```

And inherited as such:

```
class Direct3D : public Infinity{
public:
    Direct3D();
    ~Direct3D();
    IDXGISwapChain          *Swapchain; //Display modes.
    ID3D11Device            *Device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext     *DeviceContext;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView  *RenderTargetView;

    void D3D_Start(int width, int height);
    void D3D_Render();
    void D3D_Terminate();
}Direct3D;
```

Checked the value for `SwapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;` at runtime and it's null. (`0x00000000`) and I think that's what is causing `Swapchain->GetBuffer` to fail, since `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` needs a working `HWND`. If this is true, Why is `ShowWindow()` successful?

Edit: I should also add that `ShowWindow()`is in a similar class inheriting from `class Infinity`:

```
class Windows : public Infinity{
public:
    Windows();
    ~Windows();
    bool DisplayWindow(int width, int height, HINSTANCE hInstance);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
}Windows;
```

Comment: hWnd isn't a global in your code, it's a data member.

Comment: @NmdMystery Shouldn't `hWnd` act as a global in this class structure? Both classes inherit from `Infinity`

Comment: No, because it's an instance variable.  All instance variables are local to an object.  If you instantiate an object of type Window, and then another object of type Direct3D, they're going to each have their own instance of hWnd.  What you probably want to do is make hWnd `static`, so that there is only ever one copy of hWnd and all inheriting classes have access to it (this is, of course, if you only ever plan to make one window).

Comment: Hmm, I've tried that and received `LNK2001`, `LNK1120` (`Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct HWND__ * Infinity::hWnd" (?hWnd@Infinity@@2PAUHWND__@@A) c:\Users\...\Win32Project3.obj Win32Project3 
`)Only 1 window-

Comment: You also have to declare it outside the class in your cpp file, like this: `HWND Infinity::hWnd = NULL;`.  Note though, that my suggestion may not be the design you want in the long run.

Comment: It did work. In short, I must declare static members separately in the implementation like functions?

Comment: Yes.  I don't know precisely why you're forced to do this, but it probably has something to do with giving you more control over what compilation unit the variable is part of.

Comment: Thanks, this can get put down as answer. If I could post memes, You'd get a zealous Sean Connery saying, "Give that man some gold!".

Comment: @Nmd is right this is likely the wrong solution

Comment: @David Very well may be... This is the best I could come up with with my understanding. It might be inefficient, but as I run into problems that require me to redesign majorly, I appreciate the importance of the solutions. ...Unless I'm just doing it wrong. in which case, any resources on getting game design data structure done right done be... ahem, more appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    int memA;
    static int memB;
};

int A::memB = 0;

class B : public A {};

class C : public A {};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;

    a.memA = 4;
    b.memA = 5;
    c.memA = 6;

    A::memB = 4;
    B::memB = 5;
    C::memB = 6;

    printf("a.memA = %d\n", a.memA);
    printf("b.memA = %d\n", b.memA);
    printf("c.memA = %d\n", c.memA);

    printf("A::memB = %d\n", A::memB);
    printf("B::memB = %d\n", B::memB);
    printf("C::memB = %d\n", C::memB);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
a.memA = 4
b.memA = 5
c.memA = 6
A::memB = 6
B::memB = 6
C::memB = 6
```

By making a member static, you ensure that: A) There is only ever one instance of that member and B) All child classes have direct access to that member (assuming it isn't private).  Your hWnd is not global as your code is written, however making it static will accomplish what you want.

The following code does this:

```
//header file
class Infinity {
public:
    static HWND hWnd;
};

//cpp file
HWND Infinity::hWnd = NULL;
```

Your Direct3D class will be able to access the non-null hWnd written to by your Window class.  This is only a valid solution if you intend to create one window - otherwise, you will have to resort to a more complicated parent-child relationship between the two classes (probably without using inheritance).